# In what OS should I host subversion?

Tags: windows, linux, svn

I have decided to go with Subversion for a source control repository for my personal and side projects and I'm now trying to decide what OS to use.  Currently my file server for my home network is Windows 7 beta.  I'm wondering if I should wipe it and install Windows Server 2008 instead?  Basically I'd like to know if there are things I could take advantage with a server OS that I can't with Windows 7.  First thing that comes to mind is accessing subversion remotely with a VPN connection.

I'm a .net developer, but have dabbled in Linux a bit so I'm not completely turned off to the idea of an ubuntu or debian server...

Comment: I don't know is this programming related or more a serverfault thing?

Comment: Nah, it can't be serverfault:  this is his home gear, not his (her?) workplace.  This is "educational", not "please help me get the servers back up, real soon!"  :-)

Comment: i wasn't aware of serverfault...  i'll check it out.  and you are correct this is just for my home setup.

Comment: Actually this probably is a ServerFault question - ServerFault isn't just for problems you run into at the workplace, it's for server-/sysadmin-related questions of all sorts.  And running an SVN server most certainly is a sysadmin-type question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine the installation and configuration process might go off with fewer hitches if installed on Linux, just because of the package management, but that's assuming some experience with the package system of $whatever_distro. If you're comfortable with Windows, Subversion works perfectly well on there. I've set it up on both, but prefer the Linux installation process (easier Apache integration, in my view), but I had pre-existing Linux experience.

If you're familiar with Windows, I bet you'll find the installation and configuration process easier there. As others have said, many of the tools are cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a Subversion server on Windows or Linux (or whatever) so it really doesn't matter. Pick whichever one you already have and feel most comfortable with. Since you are a Windows developer I see no real reason to toss Linux into the mix though.

Comment: It depends if the goal is to learn Subversion or learn something new. If you want to learn something new, by all means do so. The point is there's no *need* or even any advantage in using Linux for something as simple as an SVN server.

Comment: I've been down the "I want to learn something new so I'll install 10+ flavors of linux road"  and I enjoyed it very much!!  But in my experience I've found it's a bit more work to get windows and linux machines talking.  So I would have to have good reason to go with Linux, but like I said in the initial post, I'm open to suggestions as to why Linux would serve better for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 will be able to host Subversion with no problems whatsoever..

If your file-server is already setup and working under Windows 7, I'd say stick with that.. Adding SVN is no reason to install a new OS

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to minimize the amount of work you put into the maintenance of subversion, go with the OS you are most comfortable with. Many maintenance scripts, and subversion hooks are written and available in perl and python which are available for both windows and linux.

Answer (score 1):

One advantage to the Windows server OSes over their client counterparts is that the client OSes are limited as to the number of inbound connections.  If you are going to be the only person working on the repo, this may not make a difference.  However, if there are multiple people, then this would be an issue.  XP Pro/Vista Ultimate are limited by Microsoft to 10 inbound connections.  I cannot speak for Windows 7.

Comment: only one connection.  this is just for my side projects and personal stuff.

Answer (score 1):

To make life easy, try [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/). For personal projects there's no reason to setup a separate server just for SVN.

Comment: Actually I do like the idea of keeping my source code repository on a separate machine from my development machine to have a separate backup.

Comment: A separate hard drive would be a tad cheaper than a separate server.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a server at all to use subversion.

If you've already got a file server on your home network, and you're doing this only for you and your personal projects, just use a subversion client such as TortoiseSVN and create your repository (or repositories) on your file server via network share (or mapped network drive, etc).

I wouldn't recommend this for multi-user setups (unless each has their own repository), but for a single user this is the simplest option. And using this approach, to answer your question, you wouldn't gain anything by switching to a server OS such as Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually recommend going with a hosted Subversion provider instead of setting up Subversion on Windows or getting a second server for that purpose.  I work for [ProjectLocker](http://www.projectlocker.com), but if you Google "subversion hosting", you'll see there are a number of providers that offer free or reasonably priced solutions.  The advantages:

- It's a hosting provider's primary job to keep your code safe, secure, and accessible, so they focus on uptime, backups, and security monitoring so you don't have to
- You don't have to learn how to be a system administrator or Subversion administrator; several providers have user interfaces that make it easy to manage users and permissions.
- Hosting instead of DIY lets you focus on what you actually care about: writing great software

I suggest you take a look at ProjectLocker and some of the other providers and decide which one is right for you.  You may decide that doing it yourself is the best option for you, but for many people in your situation, a hosted solution has met their needs.

Comment: this is good advice - i took the middle path setting up a cloud server on Rackspace but still managing my own OS (which is Debian 5.0).  It's been working great for several months now.